# Passing PHP arguments to function call not working

Tags: php, function

I have a `SELECT` prepared statement in my script which echoes  the following markup for each result:

```php
'<div class="checkboxwrapper"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="' . $userid . '">' . $name . '</div>'
```

Having all of this extra code in my mark-up seems somewhat bulky.

Is it possible to somehow save this prepared statement in a separate file, include it at the top of my script then simply call the function, passing it a single argument depending on what results I want echoed out?

I.e.:

**getresult.php**

```
<?php
function getResults($output) {  
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT UserID, Name, Country FROM Dummy");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $rows = $stmt->num_rows();
    $stmt->bind_result($userid, $name, $country);
    if($rows) {
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $output;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No Results found';
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

**indexp.php**

```
<?php
    getResults('<div class="checkboxwrapper"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="' . $userid . '">' . $name . '</div>');
?>
```

I can't seem to get the above code to work, I suspect it has something to do with the results binding?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to call the function from different places and be able to specify what results I want back through passing an argument.

Is this possible?

Comment: echo 'No Results found';
does this section get hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do something like this:

```
function getResults($output) {  
    global $db;

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT UserID, Name, Country FROM Dummy");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $rows = $stmt->num_rows();
    $stmt->bind_result($userid, $name, $country);

    if ($rows) {
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo sprintf($output, $userid, $name);
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No Results found';
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

and change the function invocation to:

```php
getResults('<div class="checkboxwrapper"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="%s">%s</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The function should only return **bare values** that later can be used with output.

```
function getResults($db) {  
    $result = $db->query("SELECT UserID, Name, Country FROM Dummy");
    return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

then called like this

```
$data = getResults($db)
```

and then the $data used like this somewhere among HTML output

```
<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <div class="checkboxwrapper">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?= $row['userid'] ?>">
        <?= $row['name'] ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```